# Extract weeknumber from a date in Excel 2013 using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I've checked around the web, but nothing seems to help my case :(

I basically want to extract the weeknumber from a date. 
I have successfully extracted the two last digits of the year from the same cell using this code:

```
Right(Year(wbThis.Sheets("Availability").Range("C5").Value), 2)
```

(wbThis is defined as a workbook)

But the weeknumber has yet to appear for me.

So you can check yourself if it's correct, the date in the cell C5 of wbThis workbook is

```
2016-02-12 (YYYY-MM-DD)
```

Which is equivalent to Weeknumber 06. (I want 06 if it's 6 but i'm sure you could figure that out :P)

Big thanks, best regards.

(PS. Bear in mind that the FORMULA of the cell C5 says 2016-02-12 - the cell actually just shows 12-feb. So the .Value will return 2016-02-12)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `WEEKNUM` function in your formula in addition to an `IF` function to concatenate a leading 0 if the length of the week is 1:

```
If Len(WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(wbThis.Sheets("Availability").Range("C5").Value))=1 Then
    Debug.Print 0&WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(wbThis.Sheets("Availability").Range("C5").Value)
Else
    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(wbThis.Sheets("Availability").Range("C5").Value)
End if
```

Comment: I think you might have to add a[WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx).

Comment: Sorry for some reason I wrote it as half VBA code half excel formula ^^ - Edited now

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately I get the error `Compile error: Variable Required - can't assign this to this expression` and it highlights the first .WeekNum expression.

Also how can I check that this works? Lets say I want cell A1 in sheet Availability inside wbThis to have this value, how can I code it so it gets pasted on there? thanks.

Comment: Hi, i fixed my second question - so don't bother with it. Now it's just the compile error that's my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

The **ww** number format mask can be used to retrieve the equivalent of the [WEEKNUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WEEKNUM-function-E5C43A03-B4AB-426C-B411-B18C13C75340).

```
Debug.Print Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Availability").Range("C5").Value, "ww")
Debug.Print Right("0" & Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Availability").Range("C5").Value, "ww"), 2)
```

For 01-Mar-2016, this returns 10. I get **7** not **6** for 12-Feb-2016 in both the ww format mask and the WEEKNUM function. If you want to return **6** (or 06) then you will have to use the [ISOWEEKNUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ISOWEEKNUM-function-1C2D0AFE-D25B-4AB1-8894-8D0520E90E0E)¹.

```
Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.IsoWeekNum(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Availability").Range("C5").Value)
Debug.Print Right("0" & WorksheetFunction.IsoWeekNum(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Availability").Range("C5").Value), 2)
```

---

¹ <sub>The [ISOWEEKNUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ISOWEEKNUM-function-1C2D0AFE-D25B-4AB1-8894-8D0520E90E0E) was introduced with Excel 2013. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>
[excel-2013](/questions/tagged/excel-2013)

Comment: Hey, i probably should've mentione it above, but i hope those guys see it here. I want to add the weeknumber here: `wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C6") = "w." & Right(Year(wbThis.Sheets("Availability").Range("C5").Value), 2) & 'WEEKNUMBER CODE HERE`
How would I go about so the number gets added beside the last digits of the year? Thanks.

Comment: Hi - i fixed this by just adding `wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C6") = "w." & Right(Year(wbThis.Sheets("Availability").Range("C5").Value), 2) & 'WEEKNUMBER CODE HERE`
to both the if and else exprssion. When I use ISOWeekNum i get automation error and when i just use WeekNum i get compiler error described above.